# Drinkability for NV wines in Cellartracker

Tags: cellaring

On *[www.cellartracker.com](http://www.cellartracker.com/Default.asp)* you can declare which wines you have purchased and their vintage, etc. There is also a "drinkability"/"drinking window" field where you can recommend when a particaular wine should be opened. This is a valuable feature for vintage wines but for non-vintage it is completely useless unless specifying which year the wine was bottled/cellared.

**What is the recommendation when adding NV wines to my cellar?**
Is to create a new wine (based on the existing NV wine) and add the designation (Mise en Cave 20xx)? Has this been discussed?

Comment: Are you asking how to list things on Cellartracker, or are you asking about deciding when to drink your NV wines?  Thanks.

Comment: I ask what to do using cellartracker when I have purchased a non-vintage wine. If adding it as NV the drinkability is always incorrect since the recommendations could be based on NV wines that were cellared years ago